# "Gview.exe" in Linux is not responding

Tags: software, computational-chemistry, gaussian, visualization-software

I successfuly installed g16 and gview6 under fedora linux , the issue  that I have is when I open gview after few seconds it stopped and a message is displayed on my screen [image]

Comment: Have you successfully used Gview on this machine before? If so, what are the differences between this use and previous uses (e.g. are there any fundamental differences in the Gaussian input/output files?)

Comment: No I have never used it before   it is my first installation, is it due to fedora should I change my linux to Ubuntu ?

Comment: Did you used the *gv* script instead?

Comment: you mean the gvew.sh??

Comment: @AIme999 while you will receive notifications for any reply in the comments, you will have to ping other users (like I did at the beginning of this comment) for them to see your replies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [problem with the installation of g16 with gaussview under Linux](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/problem-with-the-installation-of-g16-with-gaussview-under-linux)

Comment: @VandanRevanur in the other question, the OP is asking how to install the software. In this question the OP has already successfully installed the software, and is having trouble with the software crashing.

Comment: @AIme999
I think there is something wrong with the installation. Because the screenshot shows an .exe file. I don’t see any reason why one would need an exe file on a Linux system.

Comment: @VandanRevanur the user said that the program stops after a few minutes, so this is probably a [.exe file that usually does run on Linux](https://superuser.com/a/48797/130912), it's just crashing quickly. The screenshot says "33 atoms, 142 electrons, neutral, singlet" which means that the program has presumably started properly. However since I'm the one telling you this rather than OP, it looks like OP is no longer interested, so I'm voting to close as abandoned.